# How to insert blank rows between data using dynamic array formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

If you have 5 rows of data with values 1,2,3,4,5, how can a dynamic array formula be used to create 10 rows of data by inserting a blank item after each element.  So the results should be an array of 10 rows 1,,2,,3,,4,,5,,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `EXPAND()` function:

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(EXPAND(A1:A5,,2,""))
```

---

Or,

```
=TOCOL(EXPAND(A1:A5,,MAX(A1:A5)/2,""))
```

---